# триггер на insert данных в таблицу

Tags: sql-server, триггер

Прошу помощи в решении задачи и использованием триггера.

Ситуация собственно следующая:

Есть некий софт, который при нажатии на кпопку "А" происходит запись данных в таблицу orders

как можно триггером по событию after insert изменить значение колонки textcol с NULL на 0 в этой таблице

Использовал скрипт, но почему-то не сработал

```
ALTER Trigger [dbo].[EventText] 
on [dbo].[orders]
FOR insert
AS 
 update [textcol] set Z.[textcol]=IIF(I.[assigned] < GETDATE(),NULL,0)
   from [dbo].[orders] as Z
   join inserted as I on Z.[id]=I.[id]
```

Answer (score 0):

dev_code
Во первых, вы пишите что необходимо сделать триггер after insert, но в коде указывает For insert. Затем в операторе Update необходимо указывать имя таблицы (после оператора Update). В принципе, код я написала. Посмотрите)
Не совсем конечно понятно про столбец assigned, если не получится, напишите.

```
CREATE TRIGGER EventText
ON dbo.Orders
AFTER INSERT
AS
UPDATE Orders
SET  textcol=IIF(i.[assigned] < GETDATE(),NULL,0)
FROM dbo. Orders Z
JOIN inserted i ON i.id = Z. id
GO
```